# c# DataGridViewLinkColumn have cell value as image instead of text (Clickable/Linkable Image)

Tags: c#, datagridviewcolumn, datagridviewlinkcolumn

Is is possible to have a image instead of text in the DataGridViewLinkColumn.
In the below example, instead of "search" text, can we have a search icon in the cell!?

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewLinkColumn c = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(c);
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = "search";
    }
```

When I try assigning a image to the value of the cell, it is not getting displayed rather displayed as "System.Drawing.Bitmap"

Comment: Why not an image column with an on click event?

Comment: @Colin Steel: But on mouse hover, the hand cursor is not getting displayed. Basically I need it so that user get an idea that upon clicking this, something gets opened up and it is not just a mere image button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a standard `DataGridViewImageColumn` to display the images, then create a `DataGridView_CellMouseMove` event for the `DataGridView` with the following code

```
    private void DataGridView1_CellMouseMove(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == DataGridViewImageColumn1.Index)
        {
            Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        }
        else
        {
            Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }
    }
```

Add logic to detect rows if required.

The `DataGridView_CellMouseClick` events will still be needed for your links.

And you may also need a `DataGridView_MouseLeave` event to ensure that you set the `Cursor` back to the default.

Comment: This solution was hard to find in web and in-fact in SO itself. This is really a good one.